# Vectorization of Mersenne Twister?

Tags: performance, c, array, mathematics, vectorization

Ahoy friends.
Right now i'm selling a huge amount of HDDs and usually i used DBAN or nwipe to perform this actions.
Unfortunately the PRNG Mersenne Twister is quite slow, so i get a throughput of around 100MB/s for 16 HDDs, which takes a really long time.
I'm majoring electric engineering, but i had some C programming lessons as well for 1 year, so i love to code.
Currently i have implemented Xoroshiro 128 in nwipe, to speed it up a little, but it's still not perfect. About 200MB/s.
So i'd like to give a try, because usually i get everything to work, but that's a thing where i'm struggeling, and i'd like to learn.

That's the code i'm talking about, it seems to be quite short, but the math is extremely heavy in my opinion.

```
    /* 
    This code is modified for use in nwipe.

   A C-program for MT19937, with initialization improved 2002/2/10.
   Coded by Takuji Nishimura and Makoto Matsumoto.
   This is a faster version by taking Shawn Cokus's optimization,
   Matthe Bellew's simplification, Isaku Wada's real version.

   Before using, initialize the state by using init_genrand(seed) 
   or init_by_array(init_key, key_length).

   Copyright (C) 1997 - 2002, Makoto Matsumoto and Takuji Nishimura,
   All rights reserved.                          

   Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
   modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
   are met:

     1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
        notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.

     2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
        notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
        documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.

     3. The names of its contributors may not be used to endorse or promote 
        products derived from this software without specific prior written 
        permission.

   THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
   "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
   LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
   A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR
   CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
   EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
   PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR
   PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
   LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
   NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
   SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.


   Any feedback is very welcome.
   http://www.math.keio.ac.jp/matumoto/emt.html
   email: matumoto@math.keio.ac.jp
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include "mt19937ar-cok.h"

/* initializes state[N] with a seed */
void init_genrand( twister_state_t* state, unsigned long s)
{
    int j;
    state->array[0]= s & 0xffffffffUL;
    for( j = 1; j < N; j++ )
    {
        state->array[j] = (1812433253UL * (state->array[j-1] ^ (state->array[j-1] >> 30)) + j); 
        state->array[j] &= 0xffffffffUL;  /* for >32 bit machines */
    }
    state->left = 1;
    state->initf = 1;
}


void twister_init( twister_state_t* state, unsigned long init_key[], unsigned long key_length )
{
    int i = 1;
     int j = 0;
    int k = ( N > key_length ? N : key_length );

    init_genrand( state, 19650218UL );

    for( ; k; k-- )
     {
        state->array[i] = (state->array[i] ^ ((state->array[i-1] ^ (state->array[i-1] >> 30)) * 1664525UL)) + init_key[j] + j;
        state->array[i] &= 0xffffffffUL; /* for WORDSIZE > 32 machines */
        ++i;
        ++j;

        if ( i >= N )
        {
            state->array[0] = state->array[N-1];
            i = 1;
        }

        if ( j >= key_length )
        {
            j = 0;
        }
    }

    for( k = N -1; k; k-- )
     {
        state->array[i] = (state->array[i] ^ ((state->array[i-1] ^ (state->array[i-1] >> 30)) * 1566083941UL)) - i;
        state->array[i] &= 0xffffffffUL;
        ++i;

        if ( i >= N )
        {
            state->array[0] = state->array[N-1];
            i = 1;
        }
    }

    state->array[0] = 0x80000000UL; /* MSB is 1; assuring non-zero initial array */ 
    state->left = 1;
    state->initf = 1;
}

static void next_state( twister_state_t* state )
{
    unsigned long *p = state->array;
    int j;

    if( state->initf == 0) { init_genrand( state, 5489UL ); }
    state->left = N;
    state->next = state->array;
    for( j = N - M + 1; --j; p++ ) { *p = p[M]   ^ TWIST(p[0], p[1]); }
    for( j = M; --j; p++ )         { *p = p[M-N] ^ TWIST(p[0], p[1]); }
    *p = p[M-N] ^ TWIST(p[0], state->array[0]);
}

/* generates a random number on [0,0xffffffff]-interval */
unsigned long twister_genrand_int32( twister_state_t* state )
{
    unsigned long y;

    if ( --state->left == 0 ) { next_state( state ); }
    y = *state->next++;

    /* Tempering */
    y ^= (y >> 11);
    y ^= (y << 7) & 0x9d2c5680UL;
    y ^= (y << 15) & 0xefc60000UL;
    y ^= (y >> 18);

    return y;
}
```

So what i understood is: We have to initiliaze the generator using a seed, and then we perform a lot of XOR and vector operations.
When i think on vectors, is it possible to optimize this code, using SSE instructions? But what's the most time consuming part of this code, and where may i apply the changes to improve the performance, maybe just a little bit?

Currently i'm walking through the [Intel Instrinsics](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE) guide, and i'd just check which vector operation i have in this code, to simply replace them by the appropriate instruction from the instrinsics guide.
Unfortunately it didn't work so well, so i hope someone can give me some hints, maybe also about the maths regarding the vector parts in this code, so i can get through it. So i love to learn about it, and look for difficult projects, but this one is to heavy for me, so i'm looking for some help this time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Did you profile this code? What's in `mt19937ar-cok.h`?

Comment: Not going to put this in a review because it's not a review, but just fetch your random data into a file first, write the data to the disk, and then zero the disk.

Comment: (I'd worry about not overwriting sectors/blocks once written with sensitive data, but replaced *before the end of the overwrite process* much more than about data patterns to overwrite with. Add to that contents of non-volatile cache (in the device). (Due to dynamic block mapping, the NV cache is a real headache targeting alphabet soup agency level erasure. Given physical access, shatter the platters, melt down all remains.))

Comment: (`throughput of around 100MB/s for 16 HDDs` Why would the number of HDDs matter? Are you writing different data to each drive? Same question as with using "high quality pseudo-random data" in the first place: To what advantage?)